# Как обрезать чёрные полосы через python

Tags: python

У меня есть фотография и мне нужно обрезать эти чёрные полосы сверху и с низу используя python. Как это можно сделать? Если на всех фотография расстояние от границ до этих элементов по середине всегда разное.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Достаточно интересный вопрос. Здесь Вам на выручку пойдут инструменты компьютерного зрения.

В данном решении использовался OpenCV. Здесь не использовались никакие дополнительные фильтры/преобразования, которые могут Вам в дальнейшем пригодится, но данный код достойно справляется с удалением верхних и нижних черных участков на изображении.

Продемонстрирую результаты его работы на Вашем примере и на одном рандомном примере с интернета:

1. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
2. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
3. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
4. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А вот и сам код:

```python
import cv2

# Загрузите Ваше изображение
image = cv2.imread("photo.jpg")

# Конвертирование изображения в градации серого
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# Нахождение границ черных полос в верхней и нижней частях изображения
# Параметр <20, регулирует насколько черный объект,
# т. е 0 - это абсолютно черный.
height, width = gray.shape
top = 0
bottom = height - 1
while top < height - 1 and cv2.mean(gray[top])[0] < 20:
    top += 1
while bottom > 0 and cv2.mean(gray[bottom])[0] < 20:
    bottom -= 1

# Обрезка изображения
image = image[top:bottom, :]

# Сохранение обрезанного изображения
cv2.imwrite('photo39.jpg', image)
```

Учитывая, что Вы указали, что Вам придеться работать с множеством изображений. Вот решение, которое позволяет принимать и обрабатывать целые папки с изображениями, которые содержат эти мерзопакостные черные полосы.

```python
import cv2
import os

# Путь к директории с изображениями
dir_path = r'{Ваш путь к папке с изображениями}'

# Получаем список всех файлов в директории
file_list = os.listdir(dir_path)

# Цикл для обработки каждого изображения. Принимаем и .jpg и .png
for file_name in file_list:
    if file_name.endswith('.jpg') or file_name.endswith('.png'):
        # Загрузка изображения
        image = cv2.imread(os.path.join(dir_path, file_name))

        # Конвертирование изображения в градации серого
        gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

        # Нахождение границ черных полос в верхней и нижней частях изображения
        height, width = gray.shape
        top = 0
        bottom = height - 1
        while top < height - 1 and cv2.mean(gray[top])[0] < 20:
            top += 1
        while bottom > 0 and cv2.mean(gray[bottom])[0] < 20:
            bottom -= 1

        # Обрезка изображений
        image = image[top:bottom, :]

        # Сохранение обрезанных изображений с префиксом _new
        new_file_name = os.path.splitext(file_name)[0] + '_new' + os.path.splitext(file_name)[1]
        cv2.imwrite(os.path.join(dir_path, new_file_name), image)
```